# Set TextView on a particular Coordinates on screen

Tags: android

I Want to Set TextView on a particular layout coordinates dynamically.
eg i have cordinates (-58.418854,-275.28494). how can i set that textview on these coordinates?

Comment: What do you expect the screen to look like using the two negative x and y values shown?

Comment: Suppose if i have x and y coordinates as (56.55,-45.67). I want to set a Textview on these two coordinates on screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
view.setX();
view.setY();
```

Developer guide [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#setX%28float%29)